# How to repair a broken .jar association in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, java, file-association

While trying to run a .jar file (Optifine installer for Minecraft), I accidentally thought that I could use the OpenJDK package that comes with Android Studio to run it. However, I was wrong, and now I can only run .jar files form the command line (Using java -jar from the Oracle Java installation).

I've installed the JDK (Along with the runtime) and tried to set the association for jar files to the Oracle Java installation using Windows Explorer, but it keeps on referencing the (not working) OpenJDK installation.

How can I set the extention for .jar files be set to the Oracle Java installation?

Note: I have Java installed to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1`

Comment: put Oracle Java first in your PATH.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Windows 10 and it turned out to be due to another program "stealing" the .jar file association.

Johann N. Löfflmann has investigated this problem and has a solution using his program jarfix.exe

see the site: http://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix

for his analysis and to download the fix.

Comment: Welcome to super user. We expect answers to be self contained as far as possible - so having a little more than "Someone has looked into it, and has an app for it"

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible from the system settings ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs)) and via the `assoc` ([link](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb490865.aspx)) and `ftype` command line commands ([link](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb490912.aspx)).

E.g. my present settings are:

```
C:\Users\marc>assoc .jar
.jar=jarfile

C:\Users\marc>ftype jarfile
jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

It is possible to change those settings via these tools. For example:

```
> assoc .jar=jarfile
> ftype jarfile="C:\Program Files\YOUR_PATH_HERE\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

Comment: Is there a way to force Windows to use these definitions? I don't have any program associated with Java (In windows explorer), and it won't show up as a jarfile, even after a reboot after setting it to what you described

Comment: This kind of association only tells how to handle the invocation of files with extension .jar, Check the link for `ftype` above to see how to set it by yourself.

Comment: What do you get when entering `assoc .jar`?

Comment: `.jar=jarfile`. When I run `ftype jarfile`, I get the same output you do, except with a newer version of Java (9.0.1) than you.

Comment: What happens if you try to execute `javaw.exe` according to your `jarfile` setting (with the full path prepended)? Does it work?

Comment: It works if I have a .jar file appended. However, if I don't it just exits. Also, I managed to associate .jar with `javaw.exe`, and the files display a java logo, but when I try to run them, they don't open anything.

Comment: Yes, you have to substitue the `%1` with the name of the jar. The java logo is strange (if the app in your jar shows none) -- you do not by accident use `javaws`? The Web Start launcher would display a logo.